# Loop through and check type of object TS/JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wish to loop through an object in Typescript/Javascript and check for a specific type.

```
interface inter {
    first: string;
    second: number;
    third: string[];
}

let test: inter = {
    first: "first thing",
    second: 52,
    third: ["ZERO", "ONE", "TWO"],
}
```

In this case, I wish to check to see if the key is an array. To generalize the question, how would I check for any type of object? Ex: what if one of the attributes is of type PizzaType (class or enum) and I wish to check if there is an attribute in any given object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the kind of type. The test loop would be something like:

```js
class PizzaType {}

interface inter {
    first: string;
    second: number;
    third: string[];
}

let test: inter = {
    first: "first thing",
    second: 52,
    third: ["ZERO", "ONE", "TWO"],
}

Object.keys(test).some(key => {
  const value = (test as unknown as any)[key];

  // examples for different types below
  return typeof value === "string";
  return typeof value === "boolean";
  return typeof value === "number";
  return typeof value === "undefined";
  return value === null;
  return value.constructor === Date
  return value.constructor === PizzaType
}
```

You can't test for a specific interface or enum, because these don't exist at runtime. Instead you have to check for something that you know about enum, such as its value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe you missed my point though. For my specific example, `typeof` returns Object if trying to find a string array. This is also the case for objects that are of an interface type, ex: {fourth:{...}} where fourth is in `test` and the object it values is of type PizzaType. The issue is there I can't seem to find a way to compare the exact type.

Comment: For arrays, you can use `Array.isArray(ary)`

Comment: The reason you can't compare the exact type is that unfortunately interface types don't really exist at runtime. They are just typescript constructions over loosely-typed javascript objects. Classes, Arrays, and primitives (boolean, string, number) do exist at runtime however, and can be checked.